# Logging to command window?

Tags: java

Coming from Web-Applications: if I create a normal java tool with only some command prompt output - what is the best way to print those outputs? Using `System.out.println`, or is there some kind of logger that I'm not aware of?

(apart from including external libs like log4j, which would be overkill for a small tool).

Comment: I don't think it has to be overkill. If you want to have the log on a file I think using a tool (log4j) may be the easiest way.

Comment: Yeah I was about to point out the log to file bit that Rafa pointed out. I mean, unless your application is a simple "hello world", I would highly recommend log4j.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use log4j (which you should), you can use [Java's standard logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).

log4j is more popular because of its ease of use, configurability, more intuitive severity levels, and a much nicer default pattern.

A nice tutorial on the standard Java logger can be [found here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html).

A nice tutorial on log4j configured to output to STDOUT (which is the console for console apps) can be [found here](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/).

The use of `System.our.println` is discouraged because you cannot easily disable certain messages that you may have needed at some point (and may need again in the future) for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Yes -- for a command line tool `System.out.println()` and `System.err.println()` are both appropriate. `System.err` is "standard error" which is where you should generally put error messages.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [java.util.logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) which might not have some benefits of `log4j` but comes with the JRE and it's more flexible than logging to the console.